# Чтение архива .xml.gz в php

Tags: xml, gzip, xmlparser, php

Есть архив xxx.xml.gz объёмом 20 Мб.
Пишу следующее:

```
<?
    $fp = gzopen("http://xxx.com/xxx.xml.gz", "r"); 
    echo gzread($fp, 1000000);
?>
```

На экран выводится строка данных архива.
Раньше не работал с подобными вещами, прошу сильно не критиковать, а объяснить, каким образом  можно иметь доступ к данным в xml-файле в архиве? Мне необходимо достать оттуда данные и записать их в БД (mySQL).

Comment: Если в архиве xml файл, то логично было бы прочитать содержимое как xml.

Comment: @terantul, пытался разархивировать файл xml... Ни один из знакомых мне архиваторов не может распаковать.

Comment: Вы случаем не sitemap.xml.gz пытаетесь прочитать?

Comment: @terantul, нет, вот этот файл: http://export.sob.ru/files/ya_feed/ya_feed.facet-id=2.xml.gz

Comment: @terantul, данные формируются в формате Яндекс-XML (http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/realty/requirements.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считывайте содержимое архива в массив

```
$fp = gzfile("ya_feed.facet-id=2.xml.gz");

gzfile — Считывает весь gz-файл в массив
```

[gzfile php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gzfile.php)

На выходе получите содержимое xml-файла. Дальше уже дело техники.